# How to compare across multiple columns containing list value in Python Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

I have the following sample data

```
ID          VAR1                            VAR2                                VAR3                                DATE
1           NaN                             [Timestamp('2012-08-03'), 'M']      [Timestamp('2012-08-03'), 'M']      2012-08-03
2           [Timestamp('2009-04-01'), 'F']  NaN                                 [Timestamp('2009-04-03'), 'F']      2009-04-01
3           NaN                             [Timestamp('2004-01-01'), 'M']      NaN                                 2004-01-01
4           NaN                             [Timestamp('2004-02-15'), 'M']      [Timestamp('2000-08-07'), 'M']      2000-08-07
```

For each row, I want to go through `VAR1`, `VAR2`, and `VAR3` and have each to compare against the `DATE`. Each of the three columns would either have a `np.nan` (missing value) or a list value (containing a date and gender). I want to compare the first element of the list against the `DATE` column. If the first-element date is more than a day difference than the `DATE` value, I want to replace that cell value as `np.nan`.

I like to use Pandas' `apply` function as I am clear with the underlying logics.

The desired processed `df` should be as follows:

```
ID          VAR1                            VAR2                                VAR3                                DATE
1           NaN                             [Timestamp('2012-08-03'), 'M']      [Timestamp('2012-08-03'), 'M']      2012-08-03
2           [Timestamp('2009-04-01'), 'F']  NaN                                 NaN                                 2009-04-01
3           NaN                             [Timestamp('2004-01-01'), 'M']      NaN                                 2004-01-01
4           NaN                             NaN                                 [Timestamp('2000-08-07'), 'M']      2000-08-07
```

This is my working code

```
df = df.apply(remove_value_if_unmatched_against_index_date, axis=1)

def remove_value_if_unmatched_against_index_date(df):
    vars = ['VAR1', 'VAR2', 'VAR3']
    for var in vars:
        if isinstance(df[var], list):   # doesn't work
        # if df[var].notnull():         # doesn't work
        # if df[var] != np.nan:         # doesn't work
            if abs(df[var][0] - df['DATE']) >= timedelta(days=1):
                df[var] = np.nan
    return df
```

The problem is none of the followings (`if isinstance(df[var], list):`, `if df[var].notnull():`, and `if df[var] != np.nan:`) works to help check if there is a list value within the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `bfill`

```
df['new'] = df.bfill(axis=1)['VAR1'].str[0]
```

Comment: Thank but didn't work for some reason. However your answer gave me some lead, and I found that this line works `df['NEW'] = self.df.VAR1.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(',')[0])`.